# Is there a way to make a curtain with open/close animation?

Tags: animation, export, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make curtain that I can open/close in unreal engine. For now I have this:
[image]
I suppose I should add cloth modifier to curtain and attach it to rings. After that I should stretch that rings and cloth will follow them. After that I'll bake the animation and export it.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to do any of this things(. I created 100 loop cuts for curtain to stretch it:
[image]
and the rings is the one ring with array modifier. Can you help me with details?

Comment: You could this in Blender but the cloth simulation does not work in the Unreal Engine. It's better to have a look at the [Unreal Engine's cloth physics](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/Cloth/Overview/) if you plan to use this in the game engine.

Comment: @Blunder I know, but I don't need full simulation. I just need to open and close curtain. So I think I can just bake animation in blender and export it in unreal. I need simulation in Blender just to make this stretch procedurally, not manual.

Comment: @vklidu sorry, but I don't understand. Is that a questions?

Comment: I deleted my comment now ... your Q was answered and accepted :) Forget it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can export shape keys from Blender to Unity, so you could use this method:

Create a vertex group where the curtain is hung, choose it as the pin group in the *Physics panel > Cloth > Shape > Pin Group*:

[image]

Then create 2 shape keys, select the second, scale down the vertices:

[image]

Create 2 keyframes on the second shape key *Value*, one with the value at 0, the second at 1. Enable the *Object Collisions > Self Collisions* option, give it a *Solidify* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Here is what it gives when you play the animation:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: 2 questions: how to attach it to rings and how to remove the artifacts?

Comment: For the artefact, enable the Self Collisions option. As for the rings, maybe animate with bones?

Comment: And then synhronize them?

Comment: yes that's it...........

Comment: Thank you, I'll try

Comment: Well, I can't get this result. How much time and polygons require for this animation?

Comment: i'm going to edit my answer and share my file

Comment: Thank you very much! I was used 33k polygons with simple subdivision...

Comment: wow yes it's a lot to calculate, keep it low poly and add a Subdivision Surface under the Solidify